# Recording audio on Linux with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-linux

I developed a sound recording application for Android & iOS using the flutter_sound library in Flutter, but I want to use this application as a Linux app. I couldn't find any library to use for Linux. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This package support record audio on linux https://pub.dev/packages/record